# Is 'clinicality' a word? Is 'Woolfesque' a word?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

The only online dictionaries in which 'clinicality' appears are Wikitionary and WordSense. I have not found conclusive evidence that it is not a word.

I am better acquainted with English than with my mother tongue, but do not know the general rule for these circumstances- do words that derive from a root and a suffix/prefix and possess a logical meaning exist by default? What 'isn't a real word' in English?

If 'practicality' is an etymologically sound word that exists:
https://www.etymonline.com/word/practicality
Are these grounds to justify the existence of 'clinicality'?

E.g. Remeniscent of the style of Franz Kafka = Kafkaesque, and remeniscent of the style of Caravaggio = Caravaggesque

Therefore: Remeniscent of the style of Virgina Woolf = Woolfesque

Is this correct?

Comment: **MODERATOR WARNING:** Please stop using comments for answers. If you have an answer, it goes in the answer box.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152190/discussion-on-question-by-hamlet-is-clinicality-a-word-is-woolfesque-a-wor); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

clinicality is the kind of term you find in literary criticism:

> He introduces an almost clinical tone in naming body parts and atoms
> of blood, but pairs this clinicality with the romanticism that his
> body was created from soil and air. He reinforces the unity of this
> imagery by then referencing multiple generations that came before him
> and were also made from the same components

[thesis](https://libres.uncg.edu/ir/asu/f/Mitchell_Brianna_December_2022_Thesis.pdf)

> How do you hope the title will interact with the body of the poem or
> contribute to the reader’s experience?
>
> At a very basic level, I hope the title effectively frames and
> contextualizes the poem. The poem’s final line, for example — “This is
> how the boy learned” — wouldn’t make much sense if the title didn’t
> precede it. I also hope the title’s dictionary-like clinicality acts
> as a counterweight to some of the more visceral, fleshy imagery that
> pops up in the body of the poem.

[carvezine](https://www.carvezine.com/from-the-editor/2016/10/9/qa-with-poetry-contributor-patrick-kindig)

> Comparable to the modernist mission to “make it new,”[15] Smith
> “wanted to outdo in imaginative reach all established mythologies of
> past and present.” Like Lovecraft, Smith focused on the modern crisis
> of “the detachment and clinicality of the scientific outlook.”

[Colloquim Magazine Essay by Maggie Brown](https://lucian.uchicago.edu/blogs/colloquium/2013/06/05/weird-tales-slick-paper-fiction-wrapped-in-pulp/)

As for authors' names, it is a usual technique to add esque to mean in the manner or style of an author or work of art. So, in the style of Wolfe can be: Wolfesque.

Merriam Webster:
-esque
adjective suffix
: in the manner or style of : like
statuesque

“-esque.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster,    https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-esque. Accessed 22 Mar. 2024.

Comment: *Clinicalism* is also found, but not sure whether it should be preferred to *clinicality*.

Comment: @StuartF Should be preferred? By whom?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive, official list of "valid words" in *real* English. There is such a list for playing Scrabble, because games need precise rules. But English just needs to facilitate *communication*, in which context I see no problem with...

> *In his autobiography 'World Within World' (1951), Stephen Spender emphasizes Auden's posture of **detachment and clinicality** in his early poems, and their arbitrary qualities.*
> [<sup><sub>**W.H. Auden**</sub></sup>](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in%20his%20autobiography%22%20%22auden%27s%20posture%20of%20detachment%20and%20clinicality%20in%20his%20early%20poems%22) <sup><sub>Dr John Haffenden, John Haffenden (2002)</sub></sup>

Obviously the collocation [***clinical detachment***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_empathy) has become almost a cliche today, so in some ways it's refreshing to see the above attempt to tease them apart.

---

If you know anything about Mickey Spillane and Virginia Woolfe, you'll understand...

> *How else would my former student have discovered that he could be as good with **Mickey Spillane-esque** crime fiction as with **Virginia Woolf-esque** interior drama?*
> [<sup><sub>This Is Not a Writing Manual: Notes for the Young Writer in the Real Word</sub></sup>](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20else%20would%20my%22%20%22as%20good%20with%20Mickey%20Spillane-esque%20crime%20fiction%20as%20with%20Virginia%20Woolf-esque%20interior%20drama%22&sca_esv=f6034427377cf62a&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0_0Cz3I1xDJLDavncf_W2O8vRIfAQ%3A1711145688734&ei=2AL-Zci0LP26hbIPx6GJ8AE&ved=0ahUKEwjIgL638oiFAxV9XUEAHcdQAh4Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22how%20else%20would%20my%22%20%22as%20good%20with%20Mickey%20Spillane-esque%20crime%20fiction%20as%20with%20Virginia%20Woolf-esque%20interior%20drama%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzInIiaG93IGVsc2Ugd291bGQgbXkiICJhcyBnb29kIHdpdGggTWlja2V5IFNwaWxsYW5lLWVzcXVlIGNyaW1lIGZpY3Rpb24gYXMgd2l0aCBWaXJnaW5pYSBXb29sZi1lc3F1ZSBpbnRlcmlvciBkcmFtYSJIAFAAWABwAHgAkAEAmAEAoAEAqgEAuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIAoAIAmAMAkgcAoAcA&sclient=gws-wiz-books) <sup><sub>Kerri Majors (2013)</sub></sup>

I realize OP may call foul on the above citation because it includes forename ***Virginia.*** And a *hyphen*, which is hardly necessary. Whatever - here's an *(unhyphenated)* reference to...

> *Naturally, they asked this scribe to give the class secretaries some helpful advice for turning the ritualized HBS column into **Thomas Woolfesque** essays suitable for the New Yorker*
> [<sup><sub>Harvard Business School Bulletin (1979)</sub></sup>](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Woolfesque%20essays%20suitable%20for%20the%20New%20Yorker%22)

...just to prove that ***Woolfesque*** might need a forename for disambiguation! I didn't understand the above reference initially, so arguably it *wasn't* "a word" for a few seconds. Luckily, Wikipedia was quick to inform me that ***Thomas** Wo<strike>**o**</strike>lfe* wrote some particularly *long* novels that mix "highly original, poetic, rhapsodic, and impressionistic prose with autobiographical writing". That's enough meaning for me (though apart from being *long,* it doesn't sound that different to ***Virginia** Woolf-esque* anyway! :)

Comment: I think T. Wolfe has extra o's.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't notice that! I guess Google just did its usual *Did you mean ...?* stuff. I did cut & paste ***oo*** from the Google Books result, so I guess that's a "slip-up" on the proofreading..

Comment: Anyone reading an academic essay would know whether the author meant Thomas Wolfe (Look Homeward Angel. for example) or the southern writer/journalist Tom Wolfe, who gained fame with his The Electric Kool-Aid Acid Test. The latter is known especially for his biting satires of American realities. So I guess you are down for the count...

Comment: Woolfesque, Woolfian, and Woolfish are all found for Virginia, although the latter may be slightly jokey. I think you'd normally use such literary adjectives in contexts where it was fairly obvious who you were referring to; certainly you should endeavour to do so. (Especially as even literature professors seem to struggle to spell all the Wo(o)lf(e)s correctly: Virginia, Leonard, Tom, Thomas, Christa, etc.)

Comment: I'm not really interested in possible variations like Woolfesque, Woolfian, and Woolfish. Providing they're understood by the target audience, it makes no real difference to the substantive point in my answer. Any string of letters that successfully conveys a *meaning* to whoever it's aimed at counts as "a word" in my book. Obviously the two *specific* examples OP chose to mention are of no special significance. The issue here is simply ***What counts as "a word"**?*